# Material Swift tags input field

Tags: swift3, cosmicmind, material-swift

I am using the material Swift library and am able to implement various controllers and find it useful. I am trying to create a multiple contacts picker that displays the result set with mutiple tags in an input field, much like the behavior of the `Tags` input field in SO itself:

[image]

How would I go about doing this? I can create a custom stack view  by appending the image to the left of the userInfoDisplayed but not sure if this will render properly on the text field etc.

Comment: Are you looking for a chips feature?